# Request extra permissions logging with google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, permissions, scope

App engine has by default an integrated google sign in features, which gives back the current authenticated user email and ID (permission is asked to the user before).
I was wondering if the app engine has an option to extend to permissions asked to the user to include more scopes for examples (contact information, manage youtube account). 
Or is it only possible via oauth authentication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can only do this via OAuth.

User API uses OpenID which does not support "scopes". OAuth does support scopes so you should use it if you need broader access to users profile.